# A formula to check if the date is older or equal to 60 days and another columns cell is equal to a value

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, conditional-formatting

I have tried using conditional formatting and managed to get the first part of the formula to work.
=D2:D999<=TODAY()-60

I want to then also check if the value of what is in column G is equal to the word open.

Also If possible instead of having it only run on D2 to D999 have it do this check in D2 onwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Generally:**
Excel accepts `D:D` as replacement for`D1:D<LARGE NUMBER>` - making a reference for the entire column.
That is not the case in e.g. LibreOffice Calc (`D1:D1048576` appears if you select a column and go for "Condition" in Conditional formatting).

For conditional formatting you should end up with a SINGLE CELL reference though. That reference will be used throughout the cell range you apply the formatting to.

The most reliable way of checking for and hi-lite for a specific value in a set of cells is to first select the cells, taking note where you leave the cursor, then use "formula" type in conditional formatting with a non-absolute-reference to the cell with the cursor,
e.g. `=(G1="open")`, should work if you selected the entire column and had the cursor left in G1).
Note the absence of `$` in that reference (press f4 in in Excel [SHIFT+f4 in LibreOffice Calc] repeatedly to get it such).

Note: Using a formula type - the result of that formula has to turn out either "1" or "true" to trigger the formatting, `AND(A2>100,B2="flag",C2=>30)`, `NOT(...)` plus `OR(...)` may help there if you need to combine SEVERAL tests.

Here is an image of the Excel rule dialog [image: Excel's dialog]
This is completely unrelated to the above, so lets add some words about the content:

The "Rule" Formula: is "=(D2<$N1)" which means that the single cell reference is D2, and the TRUE result will be present if the value in "D2" is less than the value in "N1" (non-changing reference due to $'s). As D2 is withing the range given under "Applies to, it will change corresponding to which of the cells within the range Excel is calculating at a specific moment).

This is similar to a FOR loop in any programming language; The formula will be applied to the range shown. In this case the entire "D" column.

Comment: I tried the following but it did not work =D:D<=TODAY()-90&=(G1="open")

Comment: I have decided to stick with D2:D<LARGE NUMBER> since the entries will never hit the large number I have now allocated. I have also now tried the following and it is not returning an error but is also not giving the desired result.
=D2:D10000<TODAY()-60&AND(G2="open")

Comment: =AND(D2:D10000<TODAY()-60;G2="open")

Comment: Thanks for the reply, unfortunately that did not work either. I am using conditional formatting to change the colour of the field.
When using the formula you have given I get the error message "The formula you have typed contains an error."

Comment: Then you probably need to have ` , ` intstead of ` ; ` - which of these Excel needs depends on your locale settings - I'm using English and quite stubbornly archaic settings...

Comment: Still no change unfortunately...
=AND(D2:D10000<TODAY()-60,G2="open")
Doesn't give an error but also does not change the colour.

Comment: managed to get it working :)
=AND(D2<TODAY()-60,G2="open")

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Ok. For me to learn to get it better and/or change the above... where did you go wrong?

Comment: Instead of =AND(D2:D10000<TODAY()-60,G2="open") I used =AND(D2<TODAY()-60,G2="open")

Comment: Now, I hope I have covered it better with this change - at times it isn't easy to describe things you're "used to" yourself.